# .htaccess rewrite mistaking filename for folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess rewrite as follows

```
RewriteRule ^image/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ image.php?q=$1 [NC]
```

This lets me convert `domain.com/image/flower.jpg` to `domain.com/image.php?q=flower.jpg`

and in image.php, i test `<img src="$_GET['q']">`

Now, if i pass an image url "flower.jpg", I get 404 on "image/flower.jpg", meaning image.php is being taken as a folder "image". But if I add a ../, it works. How can I fix this in .htaccess? to tell that image is a file, and not a folder

Comment: Seems to me the htaccess is working, you get the URL info from q just fine. More likely a problem inyour code referencing the wrong directory where the image file location is. Backed up by the fact you say `../` fixes the issue. What is your file structure and code which GETs and creates the image?

Comment: image.php and flower.jpg are in the same folder

Comment: what does your source code say the image location is at? show your code which GETs and creates the image.

Comment: $image=$_GET['q']; echo "<img src='".$image."'>;

Comment: `I get 404 on "image/flower.jpg", meaning image.php is being taken as a folder "image"` it does not mean it. It means that your request was not given further to `image.php` and file `flower.jpg` does not exist (or folder `image` does not exist). `\/` no need in escaping and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` does not include the dot, so the rule does not work for file with extension.

Comment: what does this output: `$image=$_GET['q']; echo $image;`? Does the image file exist, is it in the folder `$image` is listing?

Comment: @Cheery I agree it does not mean it. But I can see the source and thats why I said so.

Comment: @aVC I can see that your rule will not work for any URL with dot in it. That is why your request was not going to `image.php` and apache was not able to find `image/flower.jpg`

Comment: @James <img src='flower.jpg'> and in console, I see "Failed to load resource.

Comment: You image tag should be: `<img src='/image/flower.jpg'>`

Answer (score 0):

As @Cheery already mentioned, the pattern recognizes only files *without* dot. To fix this you can either add a dot

```
RewriteRule ^image/([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)/?$ image.php?q=$1
```

or allow anything

```
RewriteRule ^image/(.+)/?$ image.php?q=$1
```